# Построение JSON из выборки MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Есть таблица:
[image: Таблица в MySQL]

Я хочу из нее получить выборку в формате JSON для того, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать её в своем vue-приложении.
Необходимый формат:

`{links: [ {"id":"1","name":"Главная","url":"/","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"1","target":""},{"id":"2","name":"Пользователи","url":"/users","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"3","target":""},{"id":"3","name":"Новости","url":"/news","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"2","target":""},{"id":"4","name":"Список изменений","url":"/changelist","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"4","target":""},{"id":"5","name":"Баны","url":"/bans","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"5","target":""},{"id":"6","name":"Магазин","url":"/store","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"1","target":"","children":[{"id":"7","name":"Калькулятор","url":"/calculator","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"1","target":""},{"id":"8","name":"404","url":"/errors/404","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"2","target":""}]}]}`

Проблема в том, что я не могу сообразить, как мне children элементы закинуть в родительский массив.

Все, что я получаю это:

`{links: [{"id":"1","name":"Главная","url":"/","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"1","target":""},{"id":"2","name":"Пользователи","url":"/users","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"3","target":""},{"id":"3","name":"Новости","url":"/news","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"2","target":""},{"id":"4","name":"Список изменений","url":"/changelist","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"4","target":""},{"id":"5","name":"Баны","url":"/bans","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"5","target":""},{"id":"6","name":"Магазин","url":"/store","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"1","target":"","children":[]},{"id":"7","name":"Калькулятор","url":"/calculator","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"1","target":""},{"id":"8","name":"404","url":"/errors/404","icon":"","type":"navbar","sort":"2","target":""}]}`

Для этого использую такой код:

```
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $url = $row['url'];
                $icon = $row['icon'];
                $type = $row['type'];
                $sort = $row['sort'];
                $dropdown = $row['dropdown'];
                $children = $row['children'];
                $target = $row['target'];

                $link = [
                    'id' => $id,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'url' => $url,
                    'icon' => $icon,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'sort' => $sort,
                    'target' => $target
                ];

                if ($dropdown == 'Y') {
                    $link += ['children' => []];
                }

                /*
                if ($children >= 1) {
                    $dropdowns = array_keys($json['links'], $dropdown);
                    foreach ($dropdowns as $k) {
                        if($children == $k['id']) {
                            $key = array_search($k['name'], $json['links']);
                            array_push($json['links'][$key]['children'], $link);
                        }
                    }
                }
                */

                array_push($json['links'], $link);
            }
```

Comment: берите сперва с нулём а потом добавляйте по id куда надо

Comment: @InDevX можно подробнее, что имеется ввиду? Какой-то пример?

Comment: Делаете выборку первым запросом, где children = 0, собираете массив и потом вторая выборка где children != 0 и распихиваете их по id куда надо. Это, пожалуй, самое простое что можно сделать и не думая.

Comment: @InDevX подскажите, можно ли это сделать в рамках одного запроса к базе? Я нашел multi_query, но не могу получить два результата. Возможно я не туда смотрю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось получить приемлемый json. Хотел в рамках одного запроса к базе, но пока не очень понимаю нужно ли это и улучшит ли это производительность. В общем, все хорошо, код делает практически то, что мне нужно. Как теперь к этому добавить дополнительную проверку на возможность существования child массива внутри children? Типа parent_id равен id вложенного children'у? Достаточно логики, можно без кода наверное)

```
$json = [
    'component' => 'Menu'
];

$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM `menu` WHERE `type` = "%s" AND `parent_id` = 0', $_POST['type']);

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    if ($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1) {
        $parents = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $link = [
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'url' => $row['url'],
                'icon' => $row['icon'],
                'type' => $row['type'],
                'sort' => $row['sort'],
                'target' => $row['target'],
                'disabled' => $row['disabled']   
            ];
            array_push($parents, $link);
        }
    } else {
        $json += [
            'status' => 'Bad',
            'reason' => 'Empty responce'
        ];
        exit();
    }
}

$result->close();

$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM `menu` WHERE `type` = "%s" AND `parent_id` != 0', $_POST['type']);

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    if ($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1) {
        $childrens = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $link = [
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'url' => $row['url'],
                'icon' => $row['icon'],
                'type' => $row['type'],
                'sort' => $row['sort'],
                'target' => $row['target'],
                'disabled' => $row['disabled'],
                'divider' => $row['divider'],
                'parent_id'  => $row['parent_id'] 
            ];
            array_push($childrens, $link);
        }

        foreach ($parents as $item) {
            foreach ($childrens as $child) {
                if ($child['parent_id'] == $item['id']) {
                    $item += ['childrens' => []];
                    array_push($item['childrens'], $child);
                }
            }
            $json += ['links' => []];
            array_push($json['links'], $item);
        }
    }
}

$result->close();
```